# Typescript: how to define an array of possible keys in type arguments?

Tags: typescript

My plan is to have:

```js
enum hobbies {
  music = 'music',
  sports = 'sports'
}

type Hobbies <T extends Array<keyof typeof hobbies>> = {
  [key in T]: number
}

type Musician = {
  hobbies: Hobbies<["music"]>
}

type Racer = {
  hobbies: Hobbies<["racing"]> //errors, fine
}

const musician: Musician = {
  hobbies: {
    music: 2,
    racing: 1 //should error but it doesn't
  }
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYOwrgtgBAFg9gIwQS2AZygbwLACgpQRhrIDGUAvFAOREmnUA0eBaADnAE4AuGV17Lr2p4AvnjzcAnm2BQAEohTooAHgAqUYAA9uoACYYAgp04BDKaoDWwKXABmUabIewlqNAD5PlLCygA2jZSUMggUOoAugBcUOAQCMCcYhK4znIAssRkyGbhVDj4bkgesYol6KoBAER0ZNWRnim4kjJyAEpmpEm+hQTwFWhl7pU15qRhAOYNPgD0s0mcXGiMUPZhwM14pHAgaNyE2RN5sVn0ufl+RQPKQ1cEBHWksQBMzEUE41OxAIxQ82h4GAADb6LSmLhQBBgA7IA76ODoEDUbj+cS4URAA)

The thing is that it actually does throw an error, but it does for `key in T` as well as it's not valid.

So it doesn't error if I define Musician with hobbies.racing

Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't strictly answer the question, but you can use [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) instead of array:

```
enum hobbies {
  music = 'music',
  sports = 'sports'
}

type Hobbies <T extends keyof typeof hobbies> = {
  [key in T]: number
}

type Musician = {
  hobbies: Hobbies<"music">
}

type Racer = {
  hobbies: Hobbies<"racing"> //errors, fine
}

const musician: Musician = {
  hobbies: {
    music: 2,
    racing: 1 //now errors
  }
}
```

To specify multiple allowed keys just use the union type:

```
hobbies: Hobbies<"music" | "sports">
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYOwrgtgBAFg9gIwQS2AZygbwLACgpQRhrIDGUAvFAOREmnUA0eBaADnAE4AuGV17Lr2p4AvnjzcAnm2BQAEohToAPABUowAB7dQAEwwBrYFLgAzKNNnnYS1GgB8lLCygBtY1KjIQUNQF0ALihwCARgTjEJXCs5AFliMmQAQ18qHHxbJHtgxWzVACI6MgKHKNxJGTkAJWTSCOcMgnh8tFy7Qs46nwBzUqgAegGIzi40RigzH2ByvFI4EDRuQkTSFJBghPp1xtcW5TaXTIJi0mCAJmZjqC61kB7ggEZBgZA4AHdNTlHONFdxXCiIA)

---

**To answer original question** and make the array work:

```
type Hobbies <T extends Array<keyof typeof hobbies>> = {
  [key in T[number]]: number
}
```

Pay attention to `key in T[number]` - key is on of array values

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYOwrgtgBAFg9gIwQS2AZygbwLACgpQRhrIDGUAvFAOREmnUA0eBaADnAE4AuGV17Lr2p4AvnjzcAnm2BQAEohToAPABUowAB7dQAEwwBBTpwCGUlQGtgUuADMo02fdhLUaAHwfKWFlADa1lJQyCBQav7gEAjAnAC6cQBcUFExnGISuE5yALLEZMimYVQ4+K5I7smKFar+AER0ZHVxHhm4kjJyAEqmpLE+pQTwNWhVbrV1ZqShAObN3gD0C7GcXGiMUHahwG14pHAgaNyE+dNFyXn0hcW+ZcPKo7cEBI2kyQBMzGUEU7PJAIxQJYgOAAd00JjWfnEuFEQA)